# Make ctx.assert response in JSON

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

I have a few `ctx.assert` in my code, something like:

`ctx.assert(db && fb && ObjectId, 400, 'Email validation config error')`

If that assert fails, my response will be "Email validation config error" as `string`, but I would like to get a response in `JSON`, I tried something like that but it doesn't work:

`ctx.assert(db && fb && ObjectId, 400, {error: 'Email validation config error'})`

Is there a way to make the response from `ctx.assert` be in `JSON`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctx.assert(db && fb && ObjectId, 400, JSON.stringify({error: 'Email validation config error'}))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.